# InterfaceError:(sqlte3.InterfaceError)Error binding parameter 0

Tags: python, xpath, sqlite, scrapy

Recently, I used Python and Scrapy to crawl article information like 'title' from a blog. Without using a database, the results are fine / as expected.  However, when I use SQLalchemy, I received the following error:

> InterfaceError:(sqlite3.InterfaceError)Error binding parameter 0
>   -probably unsupported type.[SQL:u'INSERT INTO myblog(title)  VALUES  (?)']  [PARAMETERS:([u'\r\n     Accelerated c++\u5b66\u4e60
>   chapter3 -----\u4f7f\u7528\u6279\u636e            \r\n        '],)]

My xpath expression is:
`item['title'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="link_title"]/a/text()').extract()`

Which gives me the following value for `item['title']`:
`[u'\r\n     Accelerated c++ \u5b66 \u4e60   chapter3 -----\u4f7f\u7528\u6279\u636e            \r\n        ']`

It's unicode, why doesn't sqlite3 support it? This blog's title information contains some Chinese.  I am a tired of sqlalchemy.  I've referred its documents, but found nothing, and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you're experiencing is that SQLite3 wants a datatype of "String", and you're passing in a list with a unicode string in it.

change:
`item['title'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="link_title"]/a/text()').extract()`
to
`item['title'] = sel.xpath('//*[@class="link_title"]/a/text()').extract()[0]`.

You'll be left with a string to be inserted, and your SQLite3 errors should go away.  Warning, though, if your ever wanting to deal with more than just one title, this will limit you to the first.  You can use whatever method you want to persuade those into being a string, though.

Comment: you are right,i tried your method, and then finished it,thanks very much!When using python,i always make mistakes about the tpye of variable.