# how to solve InterfaceError when importing a variable file which has a depth-1 variable being a list?

Tags: airflow

I am importing a variable file (eg, variables.json) into airflow, which has one depth-1 variable being a list like this:

{...

"var1": ["value1", "value2"],

...

}

I tried 3 methods:

1). in command line: airflow variables -i variables.json

2). in airflow UI, admin -> Variables -> Choose file -> Import Variables

3). in airflow UI, admin -> Variables -> Create -> input key (ie, Var1) and value (ie, ["value1", "value2"]) respectively.

Method 1 and 2 failed, but 3 succeeded.

method 1 returns info like "15 of 27 variables successfully updated.", which means some variables are not successfully updated

method 2 shows error: 
InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type. [SQL: u'INSERT INTO variable ("key", val, is_encrypted) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (u'var1', [u'value1', u'value2'], 0)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

I search and found this thread: [InterfaceError:(sqlte3.InterfaceError)Error binding parameter 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460120/interfaceerrorsqlte3-interfaceerrorerror-binding-parameter-0).
It seems that sqlite does not support list type.

I also tested a case having nesting variable (here for example, var2_1) being list like this

{...

"var2": {"var2_1": ["A","B"]},

...
}

all of above 3 methods are working.

So my questions are:

(1) why method 1 and 2 failed, but 3 succeeded for depth-1 variable being a list?

(2) why nesting (depth-2,3,...) variable can be a list without any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running Airflow 1.10.3, the `import_helper` used in the CLI only serializes `dict` values to `JSON`.

```py
def import_helper(filepath):
    #...
            for k, v in d.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    Variable.set(k, v, serialize_json=True)
                else:
                    Variable.set(k, v)
                n += 1
        except Exception:
            pass
        finally:
            print("{} of {} variables successfully updated.".format(n, len(d)))
```

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/bin/cli.py#L376

The WebUI importer also does the same thing with dict values.

```py
models.Variable.set(k, v, serialize_json=isinstance(v, dict))
```

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/www/views.py#L2073

However, current revision (1.10.4rc1) shows that non string values will be serialized to string in future releases in CLI `import_helper`

```py
Variable.set(k, v, serialize_json=not isinstance(v, six.string_types))
```

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.4rc1/airflow/bin/cli.py

...and WebUI importer.

```py
models.Variable.set(k, v, serialize_json=not isinstance(v, six.string_types))
```

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.4rc1/airflow/www/views.py#L2118

Currently, it will serve you to perform the serialization of non string values in your import process when you do it with the CLI or WebUI importer.

...and when you retrieve value for such variable pass the option to deserialize them *e.g.*

```py
Variable.get('some-key', deserialize_json=True)
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. Seems the existing code in my company is too old: still using airflow 1.8.2, :(.

Comment: one more question I forgot to ask: why can method 3 (ie, in airflow UI, admin -> Variables -> Create -> input key and value respectively) handle list variable without issue in old versions?

Comment: Method 3 takes care of serializing the value to string unlike the other methods https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/www/views.py#L2047

Answer (score 0):

In your variable.json,  ["value1", "value2"] is an array, where Airflow expects a value/string or a JSON.
It would work if you cast that array into a string in your JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Breathe. It is of course not causing InterfaceError issue if a list is casted into a string. But then how can I use python for loop to get individual elements (here, "value1", "value2")? I don't think it is a good idea to parse the string back to the list.